# JPA EJB Jackson Serialization Infinite Recursion Occurs Even With @JsonManagedReference Annotation

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson

I feel like I have done a ton of research into how Jackson's serialization/deserialization occurs and I found [this blog post](http://keenformatics.blogspot.it/2013/08/how-to-solve-json-infinite-recursion.html) is very helpful. However, despite my best efforts, I continue to receive recursive JSON. I have two models - we will call them Company and Employee.

```
Company and Employee are joined in the database in a normalized table mapping FK's COMPANY_ID to EMPLOYEE_ID
When an Employee moves to another Company, they are still an Employee.
Companies have a 1:N relationship with Employees
```

From the Employee model:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name="COMPANY_EMPLOYEE",
        joinColumns =
            { @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID") },
        inverseJoinColumns =
            { @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID") })
@JsonManagedReference
private Company company;

public Company getCompany() { return this.Company; }
public void setCompany(Company company) {this.company = company;}
```

Now, from the Company model:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
@JsonBackReference
private List<Employee> employees;

public List<Employee> getEmployees() { return employees; }

public void setEmployees(List<Employees> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}
```

Do I need `@JsonIgnore` on my getters or something? Anybody have a clue what I am missing here? I want employees to NOT show up when retrieving a company or companies. I DO want a company to appear for every employee, however.

Comment: Did you try putting JsonIgnore on the getters? Did it give the expected effect?